# JSON array in onclick() attribute

Tags: javascript, json

I want to pass php array in a javascript image `onclick()` function so I encode my array in JSON but when I click on my image nothing happens :

**Things I've tried but :**

- Put my image in a link with `onclick()` on `<a>`.
- Put quotes / single quotes before : ''.
- Moving my javascript include after/before the function or at the end before /body.

**Infos :**

- If I `alert()` my json array directly in php it works.
- When I inspect my image the JSON array is present in attribute.

** JS function :**

```html
 function loadTaille(img,tab){
 
 alert(img)
 console.log(tab)
  
  }
```

**PHP file :**

```html
<?php $attribJSON = json_encode($attribProduit); ?>
 
 <img id = "cl1" src=""  style="cursor:hand" alt = "couleur 1 " onclick="loadTaille(this,'<?php echo $attribJSON ?>');"/>
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It's very difficult to debug your problem without seeing example code. Post some code so that we can help!

Comment: Put code instead of pictures please... use `console.log()` instead of  `alert()`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/185/

Comment: What kind of array are you trying to send to the JavaScript function? What should the function do with the array? You need to be more specific to get a good answer.

Comment: You need to put `htmlspecialchars()` around `json_encode()`. Otherwise the double quotes in the JSON will end the `onclick="..."` attribute. Things would be much easier if you did this with unobtrusive Javascript instead of encoding everything in the `onclick`.

Comment: Sorry for the image im ne on  stackoverflow;
Thanks Barmar it works, and thanks for the advice i will try to do that :)